# Portfolio Project Management option and strategies

Tags: project-management

What tools are available for tracking a portfolio containing a large number of individual projects run by a team of project managers? The projects would range from studies, designs and construction plus a range of budgets. There could be 90+ jobs on the go at a time.

I thought a MS Project file contain summary programs for each project's key milestones may be the simplest way to track progress, cash flow projections and internal resourcing. I would have thought that it could be updated in the last week of the month?

I would appreciate any strategies or guidance on managing this situation and how one person could track and monitor this volume

Answer (score 1):

[project-open.com](http://www.project-open.com) is open-source and allows you to maintain a list of projects together with budgets, assignments etc. You can import a MS-Project schedule for each of the projects.
Disclaimer: I'm part of the ]po[ team.